# How can I select multiple values from a grouped table that need to be under order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

Only way I have been able to achieve my result was to create something that is in my eyes very ugly, it takes ages to process the query but was unable to come up with anything simpler that that:

```
SELECT 
*, COUNT(Application.id) AS count, 
(SELECT id FROM applications WHERE identifier = Application.identifier AND platform = Application.platform ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS id, 
(SELECT location FROM applications WHERE identifier = Application.identifier AND platform = Application.platform ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS location, 
(SELECT name FROM applications WHERE identifier = Application.identifier AND platform = Application.platform ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS name, 
(SELECT version FROM applications WHERE identifier = Application.identifier AND platform = Application.platform ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS version, 
(SELECT created FROM applications WHERE identifier = Application.identifier AND platform = Application.platform ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS created 
FROM `enterpriseappstore`.`applications` AS `Application` 
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY `Application`.`identifier`, `Application`.`platform` 
ORDER BY `Application`.`name` ASC, `Application`.`created` DESC
```

Please note the ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1 in every subquery that makes sure only the latest application has been selected ... everything is in cakePHP project here (like 97):
https://github.com/Ridiculous-Innovations/EnterpriseAppStore/blob/master/web/app/Model/Application.php

For your reference, there is a table and some sample data, the iDeviant app with Latest in it's name should be the one on the top of the group:

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `identifier` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `platform` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `size` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sort` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000',
  `config` text NOT NULL,
  `location` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`,`identifier`,`platform`,`sort`),
  KEY `version` (`version`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `applications`
--

INSERT INTO `applications` (`id`, `name`, `identifier`, `url`, `platform`, `version`, `size`, `sort`, `config`, `location`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 'iDeviant', 'com.fuerteint.iDeviant', '', 1, '4.0', 1059404, 1000, '{"plist":{"CFBundleDisplayName":"iDeviant","CFBundleName":"iDeviant","DTXcode":"0501","DTSDKName":"iphoneos7.0","UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"CFBundleIcons~ipad":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60","AppIcon76x76"]}},"DTSDKBuild":"11B508","CFBundleDevelopmentRegion":"en","CFBundleVersion":"1.0","BuildMachineOSBuild":"13A603","DTPlatformName":"iphoneos","CFBundleShortVersionString":"4.0","CFBundlePackageType":"APPL","CFBundleSupportedPlatforms":["iPhoneOS"],"CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities":["armv7"],"DTCompiler":"com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0","CFBundleExecutable":"iDeviant","UILaunchImages":[{"UILaunchImageOrientation":"Portrait","UILaunchImageName":"LaunchImage-700-568h","UILaunchImageSize":"{320, 568}","UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion":"7.0"}],"CFBundleResourceSpecification":"ResourceRules.plist","MinimumOSVersion":"7.0","UIDeviceFamily":[1],"UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance":false,"DTXcodeBuild":"5A2053","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.fuerteint.iDeviant","UIAppFonts":["FontAwesome.ttf"],"CFBundleSignature":"????","DTPlatformVersion":"7.0","CFBundleIcons":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60"]}},"LSRequiresIPhoneOS":true,"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"DTPlatformBuild":"11B508"},"icons":["AppIcon29x29@2x.png","AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon29x29~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40@2x.png","AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40~ipad.png","AppIcon60x60@2x.png","AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon76x76~ipad.png"],"provisioning":"enterprise","author":"","description":"","fullDescription":""}', 1, '2013-11-19 14:36:01', '2013-11-19 14:36:01'),
(29, 'removeya-debug', 'cz.ursimon.removya', '', 3, '1.0', 536699, 1000, '{"version-code":"1","install-location":"0","min-sdk-version":"8","screen-sizes":{"anydensity":"true","smallscreens":"true","normalscreens":"true","largescreens":"true","resizeable":"true"},"permissions":[],"author":"","description":"","fullDescription":""}', 0, '2013-11-20 09:40:35', '2013-11-20 09:40:35'),
(30, 'iDeviant', 'com.fuerteint.iDeviant', '', 1, '4.0', 1059404, 1000, '{"plist":{"CFBundleDisplayName":"iDeviant","CFBundleName":"iDeviant","DTXcode":"0501","DTSDKName":"iphoneos7.0","UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"CFBundleIcons~ipad":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60","AppIcon76x76"]}},"DTSDKBuild":"11B508","CFBundleDevelopmentRegion":"en","CFBundleVersion":"1.0","BuildMachineOSBuild":"13A603","DTPlatformName":"iphoneos","CFBundleShortVersionString":"4.0","CFBundlePackageType":"APPL","CFBundleSupportedPlatforms":["iPhoneOS"],"CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities":["armv7"],"DTCompiler":"com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0","CFBundleExecutable":"iDeviant","UILaunchImages":[{"UILaunchImageOrientation":"Portrait","UILaunchImageName":"LaunchImage-700-568h","UILaunchImageSize":"{320, 568}","UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion":"7.0"}],"CFBundleResourceSpecification":"ResourceRules.plist","MinimumOSVersion":"7.0","UIDeviceFamily":[1],"UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance":false,"DTXcodeBuild":"5A2053","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.fuerteint.iDeviant","UIAppFonts":["FontAwesome.ttf"],"CFBundleSignature":"????","DTPlatformVersion":"7.0","CFBundleIcons":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60"]}},"LSRequiresIPhoneOS":true,"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"DTPlatformBuild":"11B508"},"icons":["AppIcon29x29@2x.png","AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon29x29~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40@2x.png","AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40~ipad.png","AppIcon60x60@2x.png","AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon76x76~ipad.png"],"provisioning":"enterprise"}', 0, '2013-11-20 21:08:09', '2013-11-20 21:08:09'),
(31, 'iDeviant', 'com.fuerteint.iDeviant', '', 1, '4.0', 1059404, 1000, '{"plist":{"CFBundleDisplayName":"iDeviant","CFBundleName":"iDeviant","DTXcode":"0501","DTSDKName":"iphoneos7.0","UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"CFBundleIcons~ipad":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60","AppIcon76x76"]}},"DTSDKBuild":"11B508","CFBundleDevelopmentRegion":"en","CFBundleVersion":"1.0","BuildMachineOSBuild":"13A603","DTPlatformName":"iphoneos","CFBundleShortVersionString":"4.0","CFBundlePackageType":"APPL","CFBundleSupportedPlatforms":["iPhoneOS"],"CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities":["armv7"],"DTCompiler":"com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0","CFBundleExecutable":"iDeviant","UILaunchImages":[{"UILaunchImageOrientation":"Portrait","UILaunchImageName":"LaunchImage-700-568h","UILaunchImageSize":"{320, 568}","UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion":"7.0"}],"CFBundleResourceSpecification":"ResourceRules.plist","MinimumOSVersion":"7.0","UIDeviceFamily":[1],"UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance":false,"DTXcodeBuild":"5A2053","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.fuerteint.iDeviant","UIAppFonts":["FontAwesome.ttf"],"CFBundleSignature":"????","DTPlatformVersion":"7.0","CFBundleIcons":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60"]}},"LSRequiresIPhoneOS":true,"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"DTPlatformBuild":"11B508"},"icons":["AppIcon29x29@2x.png","AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon29x29~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40@2x.png","AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40~ipad.png","AppIcon60x60@2x.png","AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon76x76~ipad.png"],"provisioning":"enterprise"}', 0, '2013-11-20 21:08:22', '2013-11-20 21:08:22'),
(32, 'iDeviant Latest', 'com.fuerteint.iDeviant', '', 1, '5.0', 1059404, 1000, '{"plist":{"CFBundleDisplayName":"iDeviant","CFBundleName":"iDeviant","DTXcode":"0501","DTSDKName":"iphoneos7.0","UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"CFBundleIcons~ipad":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60","AppIcon76x76"]}},"DTSDKBuild":"11B508","CFBundleDevelopmentRegion":"en","CFBundleVersion":"1.0","BuildMachineOSBuild":"13A603","DTPlatformName":"iphoneos","CFBundleShortVersionString":"4.0","CFBundlePackageType":"APPL","CFBundleSupportedPlatforms":["iPhoneOS"],"CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion":"6.0","UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities":["armv7"],"DTCompiler":"com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0","CFBundleExecutable":"iDeviant","UILaunchImages":[{"UILaunchImageOrientation":"Portrait","UILaunchImageName":"LaunchImage-700-568h","UILaunchImageSize":"{320, 568}","UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion":"7.0"}],"CFBundleResourceSpecification":"ResourceRules.plist","MinimumOSVersion":"7.0","UIDeviceFamily":[1],"UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance":false,"DTXcodeBuild":"5A2053","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.fuerteint.iDeviant","UIAppFonts":["FontAwesome.ttf"],"CFBundleSignature":"????","DTPlatformVersion":"7.0","CFBundleIcons":{"CFBundlePrimaryIcon":{"CFBundleIconFiles":["AppIcon29x29","AppIcon40x40","AppIcon60x60"]}},"LSRequiresIPhoneOS":true,"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations":["UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft","UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"],"DTPlatformBuild":"11B508"},"icons":["AppIcon29x29@2x.png","AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon29x29~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40@2x.png","AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon40x40~ipad.png","AppIcon60x60@2x.png","AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png","AppIcon76x76~ipad.png"],"provisioning":"enterprise"}', 0, '2013-11-20 21:08:35', '2013-11-20 21:08:35');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(SUBSTR(MIN(CONCAT(LPAD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`created`),15,'0'),`name`)),1,15)) AS `date`,
SUBSTR(MIN(CONCAT(LPAD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`created`),15,'0'),`name`)),16) AS `name` 
FROM `applications`
GROUP BY `applications`.`identifier`, `applications`.`platform`;
```

The idea is:

1. since we sort by `created` within every group, we start from this column by converting it to timestamp. `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created)`
2. pad it on the left with zeroes to fixed length, say 15. I don't think we'll have timestamps >15 digits in the nearest future, so we're safe
3. `CONCAT` it with the `name`. Place `name` on the right side of concatenation. This is for later `SUBSTRING`'ing of it from this concatenation
4. sort by this concatenation ascending (`MIN`), so effectively we will sort by `created` `ASC` within group of `GROUP BY applications.identifier, applications.platform`
5. now we have the earliest `created` along with the `name` valuable info on the right for each group of pplications.identifier, applications.platform
6. `SUBSTRING` the concatenated info, get two parts 1-15 (`created`) and 16-end (`name`), select them as two different columns

Comment: Unfortunately this still returns row with id=1 from the example table :(

Comment: so you need not the earliest, but the latest record by `created`? If so, can you change MIN to MAX in my query and try?