# Group by month or week with Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a project which has management of my investments, that is, it takes my daily statement and saves it in my project so that I can see how much it is yielding, in summary I have a table that are these values daily, I can already generate the information separated by day and it works perfectly (in fact it is a little more complex than this what I do but the basis is this);

But now it's getting bad to see when I get a very large date range for example 1 year, it lists every day, I wanted a way to group by month or week,

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
    $rows =  AtivosExtrato::select('titulo_id', DB::raw('SUM(valor_bruto_atual) AS valor'), 'data_imports.data_import as created_at')
    ->join('titulos','titulo_id', '=', 'titulos.id' )
    ->join('representantes','representante_id', '=', 'representantes.id' )
    ->join('data_imports','data_import_id', '=', 'data_imports.id' )
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) 
    ->whereBetween('data_imports.data_import', [$request->input('start_date'), $request->input('end_date')])
    ->groupBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
    ->groupBy('data_imports.data_import')
    ->orderBy('data_import')
    ->orderBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
    ->get();
```

Briefly explaining what each eloquent information is:

**AtivosExtrato:** model where the daily income information is;

**1) join:** foreign table for the names of the titles

**2) join:** foreign table for the broker's name

**3) join:** table that saves the date of the import and relates to the id in the asset tableExtrato, it has a function to reduce the weight in the time of the searches and to gain performance.

**where:** limiting to the user in question

**WhereBetween:** limiting to date range

**1) groupBy:** Grouping by titles

**2) groupBy:** grouping by date of import

**Table structure:**

**ativos_extrato**
[image: ativos_extratos]
ativos_extratos foreign key
[image: ativos_extratos Index]

**data_imports**
[image: data_imports]

**Solution:**

```
$rows =  AtivosExtrato::select(
            'titulo_id',
            DB::raw('SUM(valor_bruto_atual) AS valor'),
            'data_imports.data_import as created_at',
            DB::raw('WEEK(data_imports.data_import) AS weeknumber')
        )
        ->join('titulos','titulo_id', '=', 'titulos.id' )
        ->join('representantes','representante_id', '=', 'representantes.id' )
        ->join('data_imports','data_import_id', '=', 'data_imports.id' )
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->whereIn('ativos_extratos.data_import_id',
        DataImport::Select(DB::raw('max(ID)'))
            ->whereBetween('data_import',  [$request->input('start_date'), $request->input('end_date')])
            ->groupBy(db::raw('Week(data_import)'))            )
            ->whereBetween('data_imports.data_import', [$request->input('start_date'), $request->input('end_date')])
        ->groupBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
        ->groupBy('weeknumber')            
        ->orderBy('data_import')            
        ->orderBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Can you please post your data structure and the relations between the tables?

Comment: @user3325126 I updated the post to add the structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `DB::raw(WEEK(data_imports.data_import) AS weeknumber)` and then replace `->groupBy('data_imports.data_import')` with `->groupBy('weeknumber')` and the same with `MONTH()` function if you want to group by month: add another select column `DB::raw(MONTH(data_imports.data_import) AS monthnumber)` and replace `->groupBy('data_imports.data_import')` with `->groupBy('monthnumber')`. So the whole Eloquent query with week grouping would be:

```
$rows =  AtivosExtrato::select('titulo_id', DB::raw('SUM(valor_bruto_atual) AS valor'), 'data_imports.data_import as created_at', DB::raw('WEEK(data_imports.data_import) AS weeknumber'))
->join('titulos','titulo_id', '=', 'titulos.id' )
->join('representantes','representante_id', '=', 'representantes.id' )
->join('data_imports','data_import_id', '=', 'data_imports.id' )
->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) 
->whereBetween('data_imports.data_import', [$request->input('start_date'), $request->input('end_date')])
->groupBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
->groupBy('weeknumber')
->orderBy('data_import')
->orderBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
->get();
```

Comment: To group by month just I just change the week by month?

Comment: in order to group by week, you need to add another column with `WEEK()` function (`DB::raw(WEEK(data_imports.data_import) AS weeknumber)`) and replace `->groupBy('data_imports.data_import')` with `->groupBy('weeknumber')`

Comment: I noticed that you are adding the values of "valor_bruto_atual", and it is possible to make that sum just considering the groupby of "titulos.nome_titulo"?

Comment: Where did I suggest to add the values of valor_bruto_atual? I just tried to answer your question about weekly and monthly grouping. Have you tried these suggestions? Did they work?

Comment: Yes the grouping per month or week worked perfectly.

Comment: But when I am doing the grouping per week, is returning the sum of the week, the ideal would be to get the last value of this grouping, I just need to do the sum grouped by titles, and get the last valid value of this grouping. For example when grouped by month take the summed grouped by title of the last valid day, or when grouped by week take summed grouped by title of the last valid day of the week.

Comment: That’s another question, but please define the criteria of “the last in the group”. Will it be the row with the max primary key or any other criteria?

Comment: Yes, you solved my first problem, i go post new question to especific my new problem, thank you so much.

Comment: there is a solution (I think) to your second problem if you describe the right criteria for selecting the maximum value from a group of rows

Comment: yes,i need create (maybe one condition?), to get sum grouped by titulo, and last row grouped by week or month group.

Comment: again, the "last row" is the one with the maximum primary key value or created_at or what? We need to define that

Comment: it could to be, `data_imports.data_import` or `ativos_extrato.created_at`

Comment: have a look at my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106966/how-can-i-select-multiple-values-from-a-grouped-table-that-need-to-be-under-orde/20107305#20107305 . In the p.1 you need to convert your `data_import` or `created_at` to `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, in p.3 `CONCAT` the value from p.1 with the value you need to get in the result, i.e. `valor_bruto_atual` probably? In p.4 you should use `MAX` to select the latest timestamp in the group . And then in the end you need to separate the concatenated in p.4 value

Comment: Thank you, I was able to finish, based on what you said, [link] (https://pastebin.com/7G56Fwh5)